# How to mock a Python class during testing for runtime typing checks?

Tags: python, python-mock, python-typing

I have some application method that uses the `@typeguard.typechecked` decorator for performing runtime checks of the passed parameters:

```
class SalesDeal:
    pass

@typechecked
def do_something(deal: SalesDeal):
   pass
```

Inside a test I have fake class `FakeSalesDeal` which implements a minimal mock for `SalesDeal` (which is a very complicated class in reality):

```
class FakeSalesDeal:
    pass


def test_foo():
    deal = FakeSalesDeal()
    do_something(deal)
```

This test will of course fail because the `@typechecked` decorator will raise an error due to a different class.

Is there a way to mock/fake the class of `FakeSalesDeal` in order make the test pass?

Comment: Have you thought about having `FakeSalesDeal` inherit from `SalesDeal`, and just initialize it with a bunch of mock values (avoiding the complicated aspects of `SalesDeal`)?

Comment: Yes, this does work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MagicMock` with `spec` set to `SalesDeal` instead of creating a fake class.

`isinstance(mock, SalesDeal)` will be `True` for that mock object & you should be able to bypass the typecheck.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

# ...

def test_foo():
    deal = MagicMock(spec=SalesDeal)
    print(isinstance(deal, SalesDeal))
    do_something(deal)

test_foo()
```

This prints:

```
True
```

& doesn't throw any type check error.

This works because `typechecked` explicitly checks for `Mock` objects being passed with:

```
    if expected_type is Any or isinstance(value, Mock):
        return
```

Code from [here](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard/blob/master/src/typeguard/__init__.py#L628)

So if you use proper mocks, `typechecked` should not be causing any issues for you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It is also possible to inherit from MagicMock and pass the type checks then..kind of by-passing but it solves the problem.

Comment: The `spec=ClassName` did the trick! Been looking for hours on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My final solution:

```
class FakeSalesDeal(MagicMock):
    pass
```